# CursorAdapter вывести попарно

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день, есть некое количество записей в базе, как их вывести попарно?
[image]

мой код

```
public class SCAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private int layout;
    public SCAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to){
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {    
        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("name");

        String name = c.getString(nameCol);

        TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        if (name_text != null)
            name_text.setText(name);

        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            String name2 = c.getString(nameCol);
            TextView name_text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName2);
            if (name_text2 != null)
                name_text2.setText(name2);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }
}
```

но он не работает как надо!

Comment: Что значит попарно и что не работает? В bindView ищите еще сколько угодно вьюшек из своего макета и цепляете к ним другие колонки из бд.

Comment: прикрепил картинку но она не отобразилась, http://shot.qip.ru/008s2U-1vwdt60CI/
не нужно другие колонки, нужно что бы отображалось так 1-2; 3-4; 5-6 и т.д
а в моем коде получается 1-2; 2-3; 3-4;

Comment: откажитесь от адаптера курсорного, возьмите обычный ArrayAdapter  и передавайте ему уже пару в объекте кастомном или что угодно еще. Задача на составление алгоритма по сути.

Comment: Пришлось так и делать!